# Find conditions such that there exist a set $D$ containing $n$ and $g(t)≠0$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let us consider a complex *analytic function* $f$ on all $ℂ$. For a fixed complex number $s$ and a fixed positive integer $n≥0$, define the function: $$g(t)=f(s+n-t)$$ for $t$ real.

My **question** is: Find conditions such that there exist an open set $D$ containing $n$ and $g(t)≠0$.

Comment: Did you mean an open set containing $n$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Yes, an open set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $n \in D$ for any $D$ containing $n$, we necessary have $0 \neq g(n) = f(s + n - n) = f(s)$, so $f(s) \neq 0$ is necessary.

It's also sufficient, as $g$ is continuous, so if $g(n) \neq 0$ it's also non-zero in some neighborhood of $n$.